# php stay of user selection of radio button on refresh of form (due to error checking or other)

Tags: php

This is my code

```
<input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100"<?=(isset($_POST['rdNumber']) == 100 ? "checked" : "")?>/>100 
<input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="1000" checked="checked"/>1000
```

It does not work as required.. when the form is submitted (and in any case of error) it returns back to the default checked radio button i.e. with value = 1000 user has to again click on value = 100, while the target was, if user selected 100 radio button he shall stay with 100, not moved to defaultly checked (i.e. value = 1000)

Where am I wrong?
Also what would be the if else version of the same?

Comment: You have to print "checked" text in input element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `isset` from here :

Change :

```
<input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100" <?=(isset($_POST['rdNumber']) == 100 ? "checked" : "")?>/>100 
<input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="1000" checked="checked"/>1000
```

to :

```
<input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100" <?php echo (isset($_POST['rdNumber']) && $_POST['rdNumber'] == 100) ? "checked" : "";?>/>100 
<input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="1000" <?php echo (isset($_POST['rdNumber']))? (($_POST['rdNumber'] == 1000)? "checked":"" ): "checked"; ?>/>1000
```

Comment: on removing isset I got this notice.. 
Notice: Undefined index: rdNumber in C:\wamp\www\aaa\text.php on line 471

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: @PrasanthBendra I have already suggest it. But OP told its not working.

Comment: you dont have "echo" for checked text, that is why it is not working

Comment: see what I m doing.. I m clicking this radio button (100) and clicking on submit button.. now the form shall return with error via php, that username is empty and it is returning, but also it shall happen that this radio button shall be selected.. but it is moving to default value again.. is it because I have not added php to the default button?

Comment: @aks : Yes it is because of that, i edited the code please check it.

Comment: dude u know javascript too??

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in your code:

Here is the correct code:

```
<input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['rdNumber']) && $_POST['rdNumber'] == 100) ? "checked" : "")?>/>100 
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="1000" <?php echo  ((isset($_POST['rdNumber']) && $_POST['rdNumber'] == 1000) ? "checked" : "")?>//>1000
```

I have modify it, try now.

Comment: @aks I have modify it. try now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
<input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100"<?=(isset($_POST['rdNumber']) && $_POST['rdNumber'] == 100 ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")?>/>100
```

You are comparing the result of the isset call to 100 which might not yield the desired result.